# Reshape a dataframe excluding diagonals

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Here is a dataframe in `R`:

```
d <- data.frame(c = 1:3, c2 = 4:6, c3 = 7:9)
rownames(d) <- c('r1', 'r2', 'r3')
d

   c1 c2 c3
r1  1  4  7
r2  2  5  8
r3  3  6  9
```

I want to assemble a new dataframe based on all the elements (excluding the diagonals) in `d` as below:

```
row col value
r1  c2   4
r1  c3   7
r2  c1   2
r2  c3   8
r3  c1   3
r3  c2   6
```

The order of the rows does not matter. What is an efficient way to achieve this? The question has an extra part from the typical reshaping since I want to exclude those diagonal elements.

Comment: Just do a `melt` after converting to `matrix` i.e. `diag(d) <- NA;
melt(as.matrix(d), na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: @akun Thanks! How to exclude those diagonals after `melt`?

Comment: That is the job of `na.rm = TRUE` in `melt`

Comment: @akrun Got you. Thanks a lot!